# How to get properties file values into arguments for @JsonFormat annotation?

Tags: java, spring, fasterxml

I'm using the fasterxml `@JsonFormat` annotation to control how a date is serialized to json in a web service using Spring MVC:

```
@JsonFormat(pattern = Util.DATE_FORMAT, timezone = Util.LOCAL_TIME_ZONE)
public Date getTransDate() {
    return transDate;
}
```

Another developer on our team suggested that I make the constants in my code properties so that they can be changed in different environments. In other places, I'm using a `@Value` annotation, like so:

```
@Value("${myapp.localTimeZone}")
private String TRANSACTIONS_TIME_ZONE;
```

But, I'm not sure how to change my `Util.LOCAL_TIME_ZONE` in my first snippet above to access a property. It looks like I can only do static (final?) values as arguments to an annotation. I can use `@PostConstruct` or something similar to set the value of a static field on my `Util` class, but I'm not sure that that is guaranteed to run before the `@JsonFormat` accesses it. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: try using @JsonFormat(pattern = Util.DATE_FORMAT, timezone = "${myapp.localTimeZone}")

Comment: No dice. It treats it as GMT, presumably cause it can't parse it.

Comment: Will all the dates use the same format specified on the property file? If yes, you can pass the format to the mapper instead, `mapper.setDateFormat(df)`.

Comment: @xdhmoore well if it cant parse it, it will throw error at the start of the app itself. so i am bit skeptical when you say no dice.

Comment: @chetank I don't think spring ever sees it because it's not a spring annotation. that's my guess anyway.

Comment: @xdhmoore well SPEL should read it when it encounters ${something}. but if its not the case, have to look into it.